# How to workaround this case of lateral join with Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lateral-join

I have a `lateral join` defined in this way:

```
select A.id, B.value
from A
left join lateral (
    select value
    from B
    where B.id = A.id
    limit 1
) as X on true;
```

that has the particular point of having `limit 1` inside (in more complicated cased I could have some extra option in the join to narrow down the values and/or an `order by`). I know that in Spark-SQL there is nothing like that at the moment, so how can I get a workaround for it?

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and the result you're getting when running your lateral join?

Comment: In most(?) cases `lateral` can be replaced with a `join` + `group by`: [Link](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/8FILgwEEZca). It depends on the actual task to say what the best solution in Spark would be.

Answer (score 4):

```sql
WITH B_Ranked AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [some_column]) as rn
    FROM B
)
SELECT A.id, B_Ranked.value
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B_Ranked ON A.id = B_Ranked.id AND B_Ranked.rn = 1;
```

This approach should give you the first record from B for each id in A, similar to your original lateral join query with LIMIT 1.

Comment: Thanks, the bounty was about to expire and I was going to have to do it myself! Note that you can perform a more complicated filter inside the `ON` or `WHERE`, e.g. `B_Ranked.rn < 25`.

Comment: It's not my question, it's not up to me.